# ASP.Net web app authentication issue

Tags: asp.net, authentication, deployment

We have an ASP.Net web application and its App Pool's Identity is "Network Service". In this application we have a settings page; there we are accepting user names. We are getting the below exception while verifying the user names against ADSI (Active Directory). If we change the App Pool’s Identity from “Network Service” to our Domain Account then we are able to verify the user names successfully.

Here we cannot use our Domain Account as App Pool’s Identity. Please suggest any alternatives to resolve this issue.

```
Exception Information
*********************************************
Exception Type: System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException
     ExtendedError: -1073740781
      ExtendedErrorMessage: C0000413: LdapErr: DSID-0C0904DC, comment:      AcceptSecurityContext error, data 78f, v1db1
          ErrorCode: -2147023570
Message: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

    Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
    TargetSite: Void Bind(Boolean)
       HelpLink: NULL
     Source: System.DirectoryServices
     HResult: -2147023570

    StackTrace Information
      *********************************************
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
      at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
      at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
         at.-------UserSettings.IsValidUser(String userName)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the process (IIS process or ASPNET process) as a domain user.  This means setting an App Pool identity.

In IIS5, set the Anonymous account (IUSR_MACHINE) to a domain user and then impersonate using .

In later version of IIS add the service account to IIS_WPG group.